# "tag" and "attrib" command does not display values when parsing a XML file with python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I was trying to execute this parse on a XML script but it does not seem to display an output on the prompt.This is the code for the parse,

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    mytree = ET.parse('scan3.xml')
    myroot = mytree.getroot()
    
    for a in myroot[0]:
        print(a.tag , a.attrib)
```

There was not output from this script when i execute it,

```
C:Users\Amy\Desktop\XML Parsing with Python>python script.py
C:Users\Amy\Desktop\XML Parsing with Python>
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong with the script?

Comment: Please show us the contents of scan3.xml. What happens if you change `myroot[0]` to `myroot`?

Comment: Changing it to "myroot" displays all the values from the script, but myroot[0] does not seem to work

Comment: If `myroot[0]` is a reference to an element with no children, there is nothing to iterate over.